# PHP - Execute code when session expires

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I'm working on a CakePHP application, I need to perform an action when the session expires; delete a row from database.

How can I detect when the session expires so I can execute my script?

Comment: Please elaborate your question with few examples..

Comment: Also explain why you would want to do this?

Comment: what kind of sessions? php native? http://php.net/manual/en/sessionhandler.gc.php

Comment: Typically you would just store a timestamp with your database row that gets updated whenever the user loads a page. Then run a script every `X` minutes and if more than `Y` minutes has passed you remove the row. `"DELETE FROM table WHERE ts < ".(time()-300)`.

Comment: I'm storing a piece of information when users login.. I want to update that row when user logs out. When the user manually logs out, then I can call the script to update db, but if the session expires, thus resulting in user logout, then what do I do?

Comment: Uhhhm yeah @AgRizzo or just implement `SessionHandlerInterface::gc`